# Who would we describe as 豪爽?

Tags: meaning, word

> 豪爽 (háo​shuǎng​)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E8%B1%AA%E7%88%BD): outspoken and straightforward / forthright / expansive

豪爽 is an adjective used to describe people's personalities.  Judging from dictionary definitions and examples, such people tend to have a combination of traits: they are (a) frank, straightforward, blunt, outspoken; (b) kind, generous, gracious; and (c) bold, heroic.  I don't know if English has an equivalent concept to 豪爽.

I'm wondering if there is some good examples of e.g. famous people who would be considered 豪爽.

**Question**: Who would we describe as 豪爽?

Comment: I wonder, it seems to me "chivalrous" could be seen as a term with a similar function. Not 100% identical, but perhaps 75%..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone drinks wildly and helps friends out without hesitation, he/she could be called 豪爽, you can take it as the opposite of petty, sissy and selfish. The most famous examples would be general Guan Yu/关羽 in the the Three Kingdoms period/三国时期, and Li Bai/李白 the poet in the Tang Dynasty/唐朝.

Comment: Normally refer `豪爽` to `张飞` instead of `关羽`

Comment: I think they are both quite 豪爽

Comment: Haha, that's alright

Answer (score 0):

When you ask or request somebody to do something, he immediately promises you or does it without consideration or any excuse. Then you can describe he/she as "真豪爽, 够豪爽, 豪爽的一个人".

It is a trait of a hero in romantic arts, anyone asks for help, that hero won't hesitate.